# Send data to logstash through a TCP socket

Tags: logstash

I consider to use logstash.

Assuming I have a Windows service that has to send data (strings) to logstash and then logstash should save it as an event.

I'm wondering if my Windows service can send the data through TCP connection (a socket)? I'd prefer so since it provides more flexibility - this way logstash can be installed on a different host that could be Windows or Linux.

Please advice.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can do like that!

Logstash provide tons of plugin. You can refer to this [page](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.0/inputs/tcp) about TCP input.